# получить элемент списка xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

есть список lisview с кнопками внутри. как можно получить элемент списка и объект данных, кликнув по какой-либо кнопке внутри него ?

Comment: я нашел решение, как можно удалить вопрос ?

Comment: Лучше ответьте сами на свой вопрос. Возможно это кому-нибудь пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

в обработчике события клика по элементу (кнопке), необходимо написать

```
    public void Like(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (Item)(sender as Button).DataContext;
    }
```

где Item - тип, который задавался в DataTemplate. в item будет находится привязанный к элементу списка объект данных

UPD: забыл добавить, что в листвью идет привязка к этому методу через x:Bind, примерно так: 
ItemClick="{x:Bind ваша_VM.Like}"

Comment: Байдингом пользуетесь, а командами нет?

Comment: команды сильно грузят ЦП. Вместо них использую привязку к методу через x:Bind, рекомендация от Майкрософт

Comment: Вот такие параметры: `(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` как бы намекают на обработчика события, а не на метод привязанный через `x:Bind`

Comment: я дописал, что использовал привязку. а использовать параметры в привязке никто не запрещал. наоборот, даже на msdn пишется, что можно привязывать метод либо с параметрами, либо без.

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, пример привязки, будьте так добры. `Click={x:Bind Like...и дальше как быть?}` как в XAML вы создаете `(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`. Очень любопытно, правда.

Comment: перед лайк - ваша вью-модель. аргументы замл сам передает, если они есть в методе, либо не передает, если метод их не принимает. да здравствует статически компилируемая привязка ) 
если это лист вью - ItemClick="{x:Bind ваша_вьюмодель.Like}", если это кнопка - Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Click}"
Метод Click может быть public void Click(), либо public void Click(object sender, Routed....бла бла е )

Comment: Вы таки не показали каким образом вы в привязке передаете `(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` или вы хотите сказать, что эти параметры без их указания в привязке сами волшебным образом передаются?

Comment: да, они сами передаются. и не волшебным образом. все дело в статически компилируемой привязке. почитайте на msdn о разработке UWP приложений. там это все описано

Comment: Да, ОК. Вы правы, я уже проверил на тестовом проекте, действительно передаются.